# create index.d.ts for read-more-react npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a typescript project,

I am trying to import [read-more-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-more-react) but beacuse it doesn't have a @type defined for it, I need to write the index.d.ts file myself (place it under @type/read-more-react),

I have tried this:

```
declare module 'read-more-react' {

    import React from 'react';

    declare const ReadMoreReact:  React.FunctionComponent<ReadMoreReactProps>;

}

interface ReadMoreReactProps {
    text: string
    min: number
    ideal: number
    max: number
    readMoreText: string
}
```

but it doesn't seems to work,

can anyone help me in how to successfully implement the index.d.ts file, what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your tsconfig.json file, you need to include your `index.d.ts` file.
You can do so by adding the following:

```
{
  "include": [
    "path/to/your/index.d.ts",
  ]
}
```

Also use this code instead:

```
declare module 'read-more-react' {
    import React from 'react';

    interface ReadMoreReactProps {
        text: string
        min: number
        ideal: number
        max: number
        readMoreText: string
    }

    const ReadMoreReact: React.FC<ReadMoreReactProps>;

    export default ReadMoreReact;
}
```

Comment: didn't help, still same comment, It does find the index.d.ts file, but the export doesn't work

Comment: I have updated my answer, maybe changing the d.ts file itself will solve this. I think you're missing a default export here